# jquery validationEngine Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'left' Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I am using `if ($("#Demoform").validationEngine('validate')) {}` inside jquery click function  `$("#add_msg").click(function() {`

Demoform is the id of the form

add_msg is the id of button

When the form is empty i am getting below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left')
at Object._calculatePosition (jquery.validationEngine.js:2883:37)
at Object._buildPrompt (jquery.validationEngine.js:2613:22)
at Object._showPrompt (jquery.validationEngine.js:2467:13)
at Object._validateField (jquery.validationEngine.js:1187:13)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (jquery.validationEngine.js:595:28)
at Function.each (jquery.js:2:14543)
at init.each (jquery.js:2:11217)
at Object._validateFields (jquery.validationEngine.js:587:76)
at init.validate (jquery.validationEngine.js:233:20)
at $.fn.validationEngine (jquery.validationEngine.js:3185:28)
_calculatePosition @ jquery.validationEngine.js:2883
_buildPrompt @ jquery.validationEngine.js:2613
_showPrompt @ jquery.validationEngine.js:2467
_validateField @ jquery.validationEngine.js:1187
(anonymous) @ jquery.validationEngine.js:595
each @ jquery.js:2
each @ jquery.js:2
_validateFields @ jquery.validationEngine.js:587
validate @ jquery.validationEngine.js:233
$.fn.validationEngine @ jquery.validationEngine.js:3185
(anonymous) @ broadcast.php:1337
dispatch @ jquery.js:2
u @ jquery.js:2
```